# trouble with socket.io: socket is not defined error

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

So, I checked out the previous answers to this question and none of the replies seemed to work with my code.

Right now I'm trying to deploy a database that will save my chat history, but the socket is not defined error keeps coming up.

Here is the problematic code:

```
socket.on('person', function(msg){
    console.log('person: ' + msg);
    socket.broadcast.emit('person', msg);
    client.incr('msg_id', function(err, msg_id) {
      console.log('msg_id', msg_id);
      client.hset('history', msg_id, msg);
    });
  });
```

socket.on('person', function(msg){
 ^
ReferenceError: socket is not defined

Is it because I haven't defined 'person' properly throughout my other code?

Comment: The problem lies elsewhere in your code. Where does `socket` come from? Do you unset it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the *socket* variable is not defined.

Your code should be placed within the socket.io *connection* callback.

A full example using socket.io + express:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('person', function(msg){
    console.log('person: ' + msg);
    socket.broadcast.emit('person', msg);
    client.incr('msg_id', function(err, msg_id) {
        console.log('msg_id', msg_id);
        client.hset('history', msg_id, msg);
    });
});
```